# can I set a target frame for a header in php

Tags: php, html

I have this code header("location:login_success.php");
The frame target code that I used in html doesn't seem to work, is there a counter part in php that you can define where the header("location:login_success.php"); will go?
This is in relation to designing the logout. I'm having problems because I have 3 frames. Is there any solution besides removing the frames.

```
          if($count==1){
      // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
      session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:login_success.php");
         }
```

Comment: Frames are sooooo bad. /me flees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP won't help you with frame navigation.

Either set targets in your HTML or JavaScript.

```
basic link:
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="someframe">load stuff</a>

submit a form:
<form method="get" action="somepage.html" target="someframe">
   any form content
</form>
```

Note: your frame (or iframe) MUST have a name attribute... not (just) an id attribute. (The id is fine, but the name is needed for targeting.